# Application crash due to this reason [NSConcreteValue boundingBox]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ecca40

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm working with the cocos2d 3.x and Xcode 5.1.1.And i'm trying to get the CCSprite Position while touchBegan,using CCRectContainsPoint function i'm getting the above error,here is my coding..Here checkpt is NSMutable Array and it having the CCSprite ,thanks in advance..

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for(CCSprite *chekPt_copy in _checkpt )
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(chekPt_copy.boundingBox, touchLoc))
        {
            [self removeChild:chekPt_copy cleanup:YES];
            score_inc++;
            [self renew_sprite];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `checkPt_copy` is not an instance of `CCSprite` probably?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue as yourself i finally figured out that my NSMutableArray didn't contain sprites. Check if NSMutableArray '_checkpt' holds indeed sprites or like in my case the NSMutableArray was holding NSObjects for which i had to change change to check the Sprite property of the NSObject to solve the problem.